# How can i achieve active(current) UserContext in some classes?

Tags: java, httpsession, servlets

I have a problem. I hope somebody can help me.

I want create UserContext when Servlet HttpListener SessionInitialize Method running. 
And after i want to call UserContext in Java Class.

Example :

protected static Map userMapList=new HashMap();

this Map keep my application users contexts.

But i don't know how can i achieve active(current) UserContext in some classes?

Other Example in JSF:

FacesContext
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

use ThreadLocal class to store thread specific values. 
so when you get the new request [which really a new thread], you can dump that in the ThreadLocal object
after that, any class running on the same thread can just call ThreadLocal.get.

check its api @ http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html

Comment: thank you for reply. But i have some problem about its.
//This My Contexts Class
`public class Contexts {
 protected static int value=0;
 public static ThreadLocal<UserContext> threadLocal=new ThreadLocal<UserContext>(){
  protected UserContext initialValue() { return (null);}
 };;
 protected static void addUserContext(HttpSession httpSession)
 {
  UserContext userContext=new UserContext(httpSession);
  userContext.getSessionContext().addAttr("value", value++);
  threadLocal.set(userContext);
 }
 public static UserContext getUserContext()
 {
  return threadLocal.get();
 }
}`

Comment: when i call getUserContext sometimes it can give me other UserContext Session. I don't know why.

if i call System.out.println(Contexts.getUserContext().getSessionContext().getAttr("value")); 

suppose i have 3 session.
1.session value=0
2.session value=1
3.session value=2

i closed 1 session. 
sometimes when i call 3. session value
value=0 
I don't know why.